# LLC Registration - Ecommerce, All States Required?

Tags: united-states

As far as I can tell, for certain, in the USA, one must register an LLC in the state of operation. However, if you're an ecommerce site, you may be doing business in all states.

I believe rules of nexus may apply here, like nexus for tax purposes. In which case, many states now have economic nexus based laws, which make me wonder about nexus for LLCs.

Does anyone have information on whether or not an LLC needs to be registered in all states in order to operate as an ecommerce company, or is just the state of operation required?